# TrimTrailingBlanks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string

In [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) documentation doesn't says much about the property TrimTrailingBlanks of a table:

```
TrimTrailingBlanks | varchar(35) | Trim the trailing blanks. Returns Yes or No.
```

so I'm thinking if is good practice to turn it on or if I should let it's default off. What I want to do is to delete blanks from left and right strings, and (by the name) is what this property enables.

Now, do you know if is good practice to turn this property on?

I know I can do the trailling in my application code, but it will be very nice to have this done automatically in the database before any insert or update. I don't know if I will have any drawback if I change the value No by Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with how *trailing blanks* are handled. It doesn't have anything to do with *leading* blanks. It has to do with whether fixed-length strings are padded with spaces out to their defined length or not.

For details, see [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx), which has a nice table of the effects. The [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) procedure is reporting on the settings for those columns at their time of definition.

To be safe, you should always clean up your data before you store it, whether it has to do with padding or trimming, setting to a specific case, or whatever. You never know what a database upgrade will change.

Answer (score 1):

I would trim spaces in code.

> You should think twice before altering
>   this setting. TrimTrailingBlanks=No,
>   is the effect of the setting
>   ANSI_PADDING being ON. ANSI_PADDING is
>   on by default for connection from most
>   clients (DB-Library being the
>   exception.) Furthermore, ANSI_PADDING
>   must be on when you are using indexed
>   views and indexed computer columns.
>   There may be further situations where
>   ANSI_PADDING is needed in future
>   versions of SQL Server.
>
> That said, ALTER TABLE is what you can
>   use:
>
> ```
> SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
> go
> CREATE TABLE trimtrailer(a varchar(12) NOT NULL)
> go
> INSERT trimtrailer(a) VALUES ('Trimmer ')
> go
> SET ANSI_PADDING ON
> go
> ALTER TABLE trimtrailer ALTER COLUMN a varchar(12) NOT NULL
> go
> INSERT trimtrailer(a) VALUES ('Trimmer ')
> go
> SELECT '<' + a + '>' FROM trimtrailer
> go
> DROP TABLE trimtrailer
> ```

From [Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se)

Answer (score 0):

The [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) setting will be deprecated (and always be "ON" in later versions of SQL Server). I read something the other day that this happens in the next version (after R2?)

We set it in code because of this (a simple RTRIM, we do it in SQL because we have multiple clients).

Answer (score 0):

Always respect to such setting for **CHAR** field type.

If **TrimTrailingBlanks** setting turned on, for example the value 'a' saved in your char(3) field will become 'a', that sounds pretty normal, isn't? however without **TrimTrailingBlanks** turned on, save value 'a' will be saved as 'a  ', now you see the difference.

for sql database field comparison, it does not cause bad effect as **'6  ' = '6'** still true if use use it for string matching matching.

however things become a bit more interesting when load the field into program variables, for example, the .net string type, now if you use for comparison without using the trim() function. such as **"6  " == "6"**, you know what will be the result.

That is a very valid request to pay attention to **TrimTrailingBlanks** however most of the time the database keep the setting consistent from table to table when using default.